# Access Localhost API using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire5

my url https://localhost:44301/api/authenticate
swift 5
Alamofire 5+

above local host is working on my swagger and on postman with ssl disabled I get proper response

```
private let session: Session = {
    let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["localhost:44301": DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default

    return Session(configuration: configuration, serverTrustManager: manager)
}()

//POST method call using Alamofire
let strURL = https://localhost:44301/api/authenticate
session.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
...
//handle response
}
```

Error I get

```
Url : https://localhost:44301/api/Authenticate, Parameters : {"userNameOrEmailAddress":"admin","password":"123qwe"}
failure(Alamofire.AFError.serverTrustEvaluationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ServerTrustFailureReason.noRequiredEvaluator(host: "localhost")))
serverTrustEvaluationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ServerTrustFailureReason.noRequiredEvaluator(host: "localhost"))
```

I have tried localhost instead of localhost:44301 in ServerTrustManager, still same error

Comment: You may need local network permissions first, check out https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10110/

Comment: Try removing the port from the `evaluators` dictionary: `["localhost": DisabledTrustEvaluator()]`.

Comment: I have removed port number and tried still same error

Comment: Hi @JisThottan did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @JisThottan did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need create custom session

```
private let session: Session = {
    // Create the server trust manager
    let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["localhost": DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
    
    // Create custom session
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.headers = .default
    let man = Session(
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager
    )
    return man
}()
```

and after

```
session.request(url).response { response in
    switch response.result {
    case let .success(data):
        debugPrint("data = \(data)")
    case let .failure(error):
        debugPrint("error = \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).